# What does Mary look like in the Fatima Apparitions?

Tags: catholicism, virgin-mary

> Beginning in the spring of 1917, the children reported apparitions of
>   an Angel, and starting in May 1917, apparitions of the Virgin Mary,
>   whom the children described as "the Lady more brilliant than the Sun".
>   (quoted in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Our_Lady_of_F%C3%A1tima#Marian_apparitions)) *.

*Was this report accurate? How did Mary really look like in the Fatima Apparitions according to trusted Catholic sources?

[image]

([*We are not alone in the Universe*](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=dP7sBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA58&lpg=PA58&dq=fatima%20what%20does%20she%20look%20like%20lips%20not%20moving%20apparition&source=bl&ots=bBgjtZS8Tj&sig=ACfU3U2yxoU2cmJzXz0xnc5oOsc2rrqfGA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_2PbilLDpAhVN62EKHb1VCPMQ6AEwAHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=fatima%20what%20does%20she%20look%20like%20lips%20not%20moving%20apparition&f=false), Konrad Kulczyk, Sixth Books 2012)

Comment: Is that an account from the first apparition?

Comment: @Peter, yes. I think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What does Mary look like in the Fatima Apparitions?**

Your quotation from [“We are not alone in the Universe”](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=dP7sBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA58&lpg=PA58&dq=fatima%20what%20does%20she%20look%20like%20lips%20not%20moving%20apparition&source=bl&ots=bBgjtZS8Tj&sig=ACfU3U2yxoU2cmJzXz0xnc5oOsc2rrqfGA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_2PbilLDpAhVN62EKHb1VCPMQ6AEwAHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=fatima%20what%20does%20she%20look%20like%20lips%20not%20moving%20apparition&f=false) by Konrad Kulczyk, seems to be at odds with Catholic statements about Our Lady and her apparitions at Fátima in 1917.

Konrad Kulczyk seems to almost make the whole situation the imaginations of three little children. Nothing is further from the truth.

Yes, it may be possibly true that both Lucia and Blessed Jacinta never stated that the ***Lady*** never called herself the Mother of Jesus nor the Mother of God however she did describe herself as “the Lady of the Rosary” in her final apparition!

> It was Mary's final appearance, on Oct. 13, 1917, that became the most famous. In his book "Looking for a Miracle," Joe Nickell states that "an estimated 70,000 people were in attendance at the site, anticipating the Virgin's final visit and with many fully expecting that she would work a great miracle. As before, the figure appeared, and again only to the children. Identifying herself as 'the Lady of the Rosary,' she urged repentance and the building of a chapel at the site. After predicting an end to [World War I] and giving the children certain undisclosed visions, the lady lifted her hands to the sky. Thereupon Lucia exclaimed, 'The sun!' As everyone gazed upward, and saw that a silvery disc had emerged from behind clouds, they experienced what is known [as] a 'sun miracle'." - [The Lady of Fátima & the Miracle of the Sun](https://www.livescience.com/29290-fatima-miracle.html)

[Wikipedia’s quotation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Our_Lady_of_F%C3%A1tima#Marian_apparitions) is very close to how Lucia described Our Lady of the Rosary, who is no other than *Mary the Mother of Jesus*! Nothing more is known.

> On May 13, 1917, ten-year old Lucia Santos and her cousins Jacinta and Francisco Marto were herding sheep at a location known as the Cova da Iria near their home village of Fatima, Portugal. Lucia described seeing a woman **“Brighter than the sun, shedding rays of light clearer and stronger than a crystal ball willed with the most sparkling water and pierced by the burning rays of the sun”**.

As for Kulczyk, never have I come across any statement comparing Our Lady to the imagery that Mary must have seemed like a 3’8” of 1.1 m tall to the imagination of some 12 or 15 year old child. What nonsense. I have read many, many books on Fátima and have never read about any such conclusions by a Catholic author on this subject. Kulczyk is definitely wet behind the ears.

Sorry Kulczyk: Mary wore a blue dress all the way down to feet and not simply a skirt just to her knees like you mention.

> The first Marian apparition occurred on 13 May 1917 as the children were tending to their sheep. They had had their lunch, and, as was their habit, had started to pray the rosary when they heard “lightning in a clear sky.” Fearing a storm was approaching, they decided to head home. As they prepared to leave, a strange light in the sky moved toward them. **The children reported that, although astonished, they felt no fear. They claimed a beautiful lady appeared before them, “above the holm oak tree, wearing a pure white mantle, which was edged with gold, which went to her feet. In her hands the beads of a rosary shone like stars, with its crucifix the most radiant gem of all.”** During this first visit the apparition told the children not to be afraid, that she came from Heaven. She asked them to pray the rosary and to return to the same spot on the thirteenth of every month. Then the apparition returned the same way it had come. - [The Marian Apparitions in Fátima as Political Reality: Religion and Politics in Twentieth-Century Portugal](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/237733741_The_Marian_Apparitions_in_Fatima_as_Political_Reality_Religion_and_Politics_in_Twentieth-Century_Portugal)